# In which case provider is not to be used in ADO.NET? Is there any way to connect to database without provider?

Tags: ado.net

The .Net Framework includes mainly three Data Providers. They are

- Microsoft SQL Server Data Provider: SQL Server uses the SqlConnection object
- OLEDB Data Provider: OLEDB uses the OleDbConnection Object
- ODBC Data Provider: ODBC uses OdbcConnection Object

Providers help to connect to the database but is there any way to connect to the any database without use of the provider, cause I have heard in some cases provider is not to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  DbProviderFactory and use OleDB Provider for all db type.
Also read this article for more information:
[Database abstraction layer for multiple providers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138850/database-abstraction-layer-for-multiple-providers)